# Melting point of water

Tags: temperature, water, si-units, metrology, phase-diagram

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_point) says about melting point that:

> The melting point of ice at 1 atmosphere of pressure is very close to 0 °C (32 °F; 273 K); this is also known as the ice point.

But why it is *very close* and not *exactly* 0 °C.

Isn't 0 °C on Celsius scale defined as melting point of water.

I referred to various sources but can't find the answer. Only clue that I got is that it has something to do with triple point of water but still can't find the full explanation.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460257/123208 Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272830/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449975/123208

Comment: It gives reference 3:  The melting point of purified water has been measured as 0.002519 ± 0.000002 °C, see Feistel, R. & Wagner, W. (2006). "A New Equation of State for H2O Ice Ih". Journal of Physical and Chemical Reference Data. 35 (2): 1021–1047. Bibcode:2006JPCRD..35.1021F. doi:10.1063/1.2183324.